# Django Rest Framework SimpleJWT - Removing a variable refrencing 'request.body' Causes 'RawPostDataException' Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django 4.2.6 project using Python 3.10 and the rest_framework_simplejwt library. I've implemented a signin function, and it works fine when I include the line `body = request.body`, even though I'm not using `body` anywhere in the function. However, when I remove this line, it throws the following error:

> “RawPostDataException at /auth/signin/ - You cannot access the body after reading from the request's data stream.”

I've tried to understand why this is happening, but I couldn't figure it out even after reading the docs. Can someone help me understand why this line is needed and if there's a cleaner or better way to write this function? Here's my code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def signin(request):
    body = request.body

    token_view = jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view()
    token_response = token_view(request._request)

    if token_response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
        data = request.data
        user = User.objects.filter(username=data['username']).first()
        data = {
            "access_token": str(token_response.data['access']),
            "refresh_token": str(token_response.data['refresh']),
            "user_access": {
                "is_staff": user.is_staff,
                "is_admin": user.is_superuser
            }
        }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    return token_response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is related to how Django processes request bodies and streams.

In Django `request.body` is a way to access raw post data.
When you access `request.body`, django reads the incoming data and caches it.
This means subsequent accesses to `request.body` will not cause any errors, as  the data has already been read and stored.

However, when you use `request.data` in Django REST Framework, it internally uses a different way to parse the incoming data.
If you access `request.data` without accessing it before ( so data hasn't been read and cached yet), then Django attempts to read from the data stream again.

If the stream has already been read (you read within `jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView`), then Django raises the `RawPostDataException` error because HTTP data can only be read once.

So can employ following approach to avoid unused variable

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def signin(request):
    data = request.data  # Parse and use the request data first

    # Create a copy of the request to pass to the TokenObtainPairView
    request_copy = request._request
    request_copy._data = data

    token_view = jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view()
    token_response = token_view(request_copy)

    if token_response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
        user = User.objects.filter(username=data['username']).first()
        data = {
            "access_token": str(token_response.data['access']),
            "refresh_token": str(token_response.data['refresh']),
            "user_access": {
                "is_staff": user.is_staff,
                "is_admin": user.is_superuser
            }
        }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    return token_response
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I understand it better now. What I still don't know tho is, if there was a better way around it other than declaring an unused variable?